# Cast from '[Any]?' to unrelated type 'SpotlightView' always fails

Tags: ios, swift

The following function takes an Array of Data Models and should go through them via a for loop before outputting a UIViews for each of them, which I am storing in a separate array. The UIViews are to be used to populate a scroll view.

The declaration of the slide is giving me the error in the title of the post

```
func createSpotlights(_ spotlightModel: [SpotlightModel]) -> [SpotlightView] {

    for i in 0..<spotlightModel.count {
        let slide: SpotlightView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SpotlightView", owner: self, options: nil) as! SpotlightView
        slide.titleLabel?.text = spotlightModel[i].title
        slide.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(data: downloadImage(spotlightModel[i].backgroundImage)!)
        spotlightSlides.append(slide)
    }

    return spotlightSlides
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[loadNibNamed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1618147-loadnibnamed) **returns an array** containing the top-level objects in the nib file.

You are trying to cast an `Array` to `SpotlightView` which are totally different data types.

Comment: This comment resolved my issue. Adding `.first` to the `loadNibNamed` fixed my issue!